# AngularJS 1 events - "this" variable in callback method is the window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I'm trying to learn to use AngularJS 1.6 events.
I created a component which is registered to the event:

```
'use strict';
var module = angular.module("Test", []);
module.controller("Controller1", Controller1);

Controller1.$inject = ["$scope"];
function Controller1($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.try = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast("test:try");
    }
}
module.controller("Controller2", Controller2);
module.component("compo2", {
    controller: "Controller2",
});


Controller2.$inject = ["$scope"];
function Controller2($scope) {
    var self = this;
    this.$onInit = function () {
        $scope.$on("test:try", self.try);
    }

    self.try = function (event, data) {
        console.log("Logged event!!!")
    }
}
```

and this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="./Test/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./compoTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl1">
        <compo2> T.E.S.T </compo2>
        <button ng-click="ctrl1.try();"> Try! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

But when the callback "try" is called - I see that the `this` variable is the window instead of my component's controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when object method is called as a callback in JS.

To avoid accidental use of `window`, use strict mode in the beginning of JS file:

```
'use strict';
```

The method should be bound to the context:

```
this.try = function (event, data) {
    this....
}.bind(this);
```

Or `self` recipe should be used:

```
var self = this;

self.try = function (event, data) {
    self....
};
```

Comment: You don't use `this` or `self` in `try`. It is not clear how the code you're using differs from the one you've posted.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in "try" and used the chrome devtools console to see the value of "this"... I used the "Self" thing in the edited version.

Comment: Because it won't be equal to controller `this`, unless you do `bind(this)`. You should either use `bind(this)` or use `self` consistently, as the answer explains. Since `self` is simpler, it is usually preferred.

Comment: oops...I forgot to replace a "this" with "self" in the declaration of $onInit. thanks :)